# Print Div With Javascript and Preserve Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to print a certain div in my application using this javascript with JQuery:

```
function PrintContent()
{
w=window.open();
w.document.write($('#diary').html());
w.print();
w.close();
}
```

It opens the div in a new tab and the print options panel opens up but the CSS styles are lost. I have a print.css, set to media="print" however, I think that it's obviously not loading this file in the new tab i.e. it's just loading the div and not the header where the CSS is.

Any idea how I can fix this? My javascript isn't that strong.

Thanks!

Comment: Do I need to have the stlyesheet referenced inside the DIV in order to make it applicable in print? or having it on main page suffices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this line instead:

```
w.document.write('<div id="diary">' + $('#diary').html() + '</div>');
```

You are writing out the **inner html** of your div and not the actual div tag.

The method above also writes out the div tag with the right id. I only stuck the id in there because you might be formatting `div#diary` rather than `div`.

**EDIT**

This method should keep the styling.

```
function PrintContent()
{
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    e.id = 'diary';
    e.innerHTML = $('#diary').html();
    document.getElementById('t').appendChild(e);
}
```

You just have to make a place that this content can be inserted, such as a `div` with the id of `t`. Just like the example I posted in the comments.

Comment: Hi @Wolfy87 thanks for your answer. I didn't realise that about the inner html. It still seems to be losing the formatting though?

Comment: @Robimp Yep, this is because we are just adding the HTML, the better way would be something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Wolfy87/49N44/

Comment: See my edit for something that should be close to what you need.

Comment: Excellent, got it sorted. Thanks again!

Comment: After inserting the content into DIV with id "t", what should be the next line in the PrintContent function? Should it be 

w.document.write($('#t).html()); w.print(); w.close(); ?

Comment: You do not need to print the content at all. The element `#t` is already in the HTML and the element `e` is inserted inside it. This is a better way of achieving `document.write`.

Comment: This is very unclear.  What do you mean by "The element `#t` is already in the HTML"?  Are we appending `e` onto our newly created document created by `w=window.open()`, and you are somehow adding an empty div into that new document?  I don't understand why you would do that.

Answer (score 0):

Because document.write is bad practice:

https://github.com/jasonday/printThis